# Can I place the battery in my 2005 Cayenne Turbo with an AGM?

Tags: battery, porsche

2005 Porsche Cayenne Turbo.  Can I replace battery with H9 AGM battery or do I need to use a lead-acid battery?  I have read that the 2005 software does not recognize the AGM and will not charge at correct rate.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Everything I'm reading shows your Cayenne came from the factory with an AGM battery.